# UIPopovercontroller's height get reduced if keyboard is present.

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am using UIPopover controller to show some kind menu on ipad.its height is around 700 px. Popover look fine in portrait mode even if keyboard is visible.
Now if i rotate ipad to landscape mode with keyboard visible popovers height get reduced.
is there any way to show full popover when key board is visible.

If i rotate it to landscape mode an if key board is visible and when i open this popover it cuts from bottom as because of 700 px height

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to show full popOver by hiding keyboard.

```
                       [self.view endEditing:YES];
```